# Catch route change when link is same as current location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a bunch of links in a push menu that I want to catch regardless if the user is on the current page for a particular link (in order to close the menu).

Example link in HTML:

```
<html data-ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="main" data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <!-- home content -->
</div>
<div class="menu" data-ng-controller="NavCtrl">
    <a data-ng-href="/">Home</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If a user was at localhost:3000/, **as opposed** to localhost:3000/about, I can't capture this link click event using things like (it works otherwise):

```
angular.module('app').controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', routeChangeFunc);
    // or
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', locationChangeFunc);
    // or
    $scope.$root.$on('$locationChangeStart',rootLocationChangeFunc);
}]);
```

I understand that I can have an event listener on  tags for example, but was hoping to have an angular catch-all solution.

Thanks :)

Comment: No reason you shouldn't be able to catch those events. Provide [mcve]. We have no idea where you are using that code. Also clarify router being used

Comment: I can catch the events, just not when the link is the same as the current (as stated above). I'll update my code where I am using it.

Comment: Clarify issue then because it clearly says *"I **can't** capture"*

Comment: I did, look again mate, I specify what exactly I can't capture which is the '/' if I am at the location '/'

Comment: There, I made it more clear.

Comment: Why not just use a single `ng-click` on whole nav? You still haven't shown what is required in ui or what the exact higher level problem is

Comment: Good suggestion, we did think about this but there is a chance that we will want to close it elsewhere also (good example would be logo click on homepage). I used the push menu as an example. Perhaps we could do the logo as a special case and try and ng-click.

Comment: So put listener on document. Not complicated

Comment: Right, I know that way is not, read the last sentence. I was wondering if anyone had solved this is a more angular way (i.e., hijacking the $location provider and overriding the rule that ignores the event broadcast for $routeChangeSuccess if the url is the same).

Comment: Why over complicate it? If I understand correctly you are just needing an event handler to close a menu that exists in all views correct? Simple directive with document listener would solve it

Comment: I have been pretty succinct in my request and I appreciate your assistance, but nothing is that simple thus the desire for utilizing an angular service that already exists would be awesome. Thanks anyways.